# Anagram of String 2 is Substring of String 1

Tags: string, algorithm, anagram

How to find that any anagram of String 1 is sub string of String 2?

Eg :-

String 1 =**rove**

String 2=**stackoverflow**

So it will return true as anagram of "rove" is "over" which is sub-string of String 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On edit: my first answer was quadratic in the worst case. I've tweaked it to be strictly linear:

Here is an approach based on the notion of a sliding window: Create a dictionary keyed by the letters of the first dictionary with frequency counts of the letters for the corresponding values. Think of this as a dictionary of targets which need to be matched by `m` consecutive letters in the second string, where `m` is the length of the first string.

Start by processing the first `m` letters in the second string. For each such letter if it appears as a key in the target dictionary *decrease* the corresponding value by 1. The goal is to drive all target values to 0. Define `discrepancy` to be the sum of the absolute values of the values after processing the first window of `m` letters.

Repeatedly do the following: check if `discrepancy == 0` and return `True`if it does. Otherwise -- take the character `m` letters ago and check if it is a target key and if so -- increase the value by 1. In this case, this either increases or decreases the discrepancy by 1, adjust accordingly. Then get the next character of the second string and process it as well. Check if it is a key in the dictionary and if so adjust the value and the discrepancy as appropriate.

Since there are no nested loop and each pass through the main loop involves just a few dictionary lookups, comparisons, addition and subtractions, the overall algorithm is linear.

A Python 3 implementation (which shows the basic logic of how the window slides and the target counts and discrepancy are adjusted):

```
def subAnagram(s1,s2):
    m = len(s1)
    n = len(s2)
    if m > n: return false
    target = dict.fromkeys(s1,0)
    for c in s1: target[c] += 1

    #process initial window
    for i in range(m):
        c = s2[i]
        if c in target:
            target[c] -= 1
    discrepancy = sum(abs(target[c]) for c in target)

    #repeatedly check then slide:
    for i in range(m,n):
        if discrepancy == 0:
            return True
        else:
            #first process letter from m steps ago from s2
            c = s2[i-m]
            if c in target:
                target[c] += 1
                if target[c] > 0: #just made things worse
                    discrepancy +=1
                else:
                    discrepancy -=1
            #now process new letter:
            c = s2[i]
            if c in target:
                target[c] -= 1
                if target[c] < 0: #just made things worse
                    discrepancy += 1
                else:
                    discrepancy -=1
    #if you get to this stage:
    return discrepancy == 0
```

Typical output:

```
>>> subAnagram("rove", "stack overflow")
True
>>> subAnagram("rowe", "stack overflow")
False
```

To stress-test it, I downloaded the complete text of [Moby Dick](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2701) from Project Gutenberg. This has over 1 million characters. "Formosa" is mentioned in the book, hence an anagram of "moors" appears as a substring of Moby Dick. But, not surprisingly, no anagram of "stackoverflow" appears in Moby Dick:

```
>>> f = open("moby dick.txt")
>>> md = f.read()
>>> f.close()
>>> len(md)
1235186
>>> subAnagram("moors",md)
True
>>> subAnagram("stackoverflow",md)
False
```

The last call takes roughly 1 second to process the complete text of Moby Dick and verify that no anagram of "stackoverflow" appears in it.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in `O(n^3)` pre-processing, and `O(klogk)` per query where: `n` is the size of the "given string" (string 2 in your example) and `k` is the size of the query (string 1 in your example).

Pre process:

```
For each substring s of string2: //O(n^2) of those
    sort s 
    store s in some data base (hash table, for example)
```

Query:

```
given a query q:
    sort q
    check if q is in the data base
    if it is - it's an anagram of some substring
    otherwise - it is not.
```

This answer assumes you are going to check multiple "queries" (string 1's) for a single string (string 2), and thus tries to optimize the complexity for each query.

---

As discussed in comments, you can do the pro-process step lazily - that means, when you first encounter a query of length `k` insert to the DS all substrings of length `k`, and proceed as original suggestion.

Comment: There is no need  to  compute all substrings in advance. It would be better to just consider the substrings of length k, and add them to the database if not already there (so this is only done once for each actual word  length). This will avoid adding to the database all the substrings of lengths that dont correspond to real words, as well as not having to perform all the pre-processing at once in the beginning.

Comment: @gen-y-s Look at what I stated at the end of the answer, I am assuming one string and multiple queries (of different lengths), and optimize the solution to it - so each query will take minimal time, at the cost of more expansive pre-processing.

Comment: I understood your answer. My comment is to put in the dictionary only the substrings of the length of the current search word (k1), so the dictionary can be used if another search word of the same length (k1) is given. If later we are given another search word of a different length k2, then we add to dictionary all substrings of length k2. Advantage is that you only put in the dictionary substrings of length which is actually used by the searches (and not all possible substrings) and also you spread the pre-processing time over several searches.

Comment: silence = admittance ?  qed

Comment: @gen-y-s silence = putting the kids to sleep, which is hard (and forgetting to come back to this thread). It's basically "lazy VS eager" preprocessing. You suggest doing it lazily (which makes sense), the original solution is doing it eagerly. I added a mention to this approach to the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

Let L be the length of String1.

Loop over String2 and check if each substring of length L is an anagram of String1.

In your example, String1 = rove and String2 = stackoverflow.

**stac**koverflow

**stac** and **rove** are not anagrams, so move to the next substring of length L.

s**tack**overflow

tack and rove are not anagrams, and so on till you find the substring.

A faster method would be to check if the last letter in the current substring is present in String1 i.e., once you find that stac and rove are not anagrams, and see that 'c' (which is the last letter of the current substring) is not present in rove, you can simply skip that substring entirely and get the next substring from 'k'.

i.e. **stac**koverflow

**stac** and **rove** are not anagrams. 'c' is not present in 'rove', so simply skip over this substring and check from 'k':

stac**kove**rflow

This will significantly reduce the number of comparisons.

---

**Edit:**

Here is a Python 2 implementation of the method explained above.

**NOTE:** This implementation works under the assumption that all characters in both strings are in lowercase and they consist only of the characters a -z.

```
def isAnagram(s1, s2):
    c1 = [0] * 26
    c2 = [0] * 26

    # increase character counts for each string
    for i in s1:
        c1[ord(i) - 97] += 1
    for i in s2:
        c2[ord(i) - 97] += 1

    # if the character counts are same, they are anagrams
    if c1 == c2:
        return True
    return False

def isSubAnagram(s1, s2):
    l = len(s1)

    # s2[start:end] represents the substring in s2
    start = 0
    end = l

    while(end <= len(s2)):
        sub = s2[start:end]
        if isAnagram(s1, sub):
            return True
        elif sub[-1] not in s1:
            start += l
            end += l
        else:
            start += 1
            end += 1
    return False
```

Output:

```
>>> print isSubAnagram('rove', 'stackoverflow')
True

>>> print isSubAnagram('rowe', 'stackoverflow')
False
```

Comment: What is the complexity of this algorithm?

Comment: @JohnColeman I have edited the answer to include an implementation in Python 2. 
Assuming the shorter string is of length k and the longer of length n, there are atmost (n - k + 1) anagram checks. Since the anagram check runs in O(k), I would say the overall algo complexity is O(n). 
However, my implementation is limited by the assumptions that all characters are in lowercase and only in the range a-z. Yours is a more general implementation.

Comment: I don't think your `elif` at the end of your code is what you want  -- shouldn't it be something like `start = end + 1` then `end = start + k`? In any event -- there is an interesting tradeoff. Your approach allows you to step though the second string in big jumps (in the best case) but at the cost of more work when you actually stop to check for anagrams. I wouldn't be surprised if your approach has better average-case performance (perhaps given certain assumptions on letter frequencies) but my approach has better worst-case performance.

Comment: @JohnColeman you're right, but I have done the same in my `elif`: I have incremented both start and end by `l` (that is the letter 'L' in lowercase, it probably looks like a 1 in the code above, it's not. `l` is the length of the shorter string. Pardon the inconsistency; I referred to it as k in my comment).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create all the possible combination of String1 that is rove like rove,rvoe,reov.. Then check this any of this combination is in String2.

Comment: That's going to be `sum{k! * (n-k) }` strings. clearly unfeasible for reasonable size string.

Answer (score -1):

```
//Two string are considered and check whether Anagram of the second     string is 
//present in the first string as part of it (Substring)
//e.g. 'atctv' 'cat' will return true as 'atc' is anagram of cat
//Similarly 'battex' is containing an anagram of 'text' as 'ttex'

public class SubstringIsAnagramOfSecondString {

    public static boolean isAnagram(String str1, String str2){
        //System.out.println(str1+"::" + str2);
        Character[] charArr = new Character[str1.length()];

        for(int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++){
            char ithChar1 = str1.charAt(i);
            charArr[i] = ithChar1;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < str2.length(); i++){
            char ithChar2 = str2.charAt(i);
            for(int j = 0; j<charArr.length; j++){
                if(charArr[j] == null) continue;
                if(charArr[j] == ithChar2){
                    charArr[j] = null;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int j = 0; j<charArr.length; j++){
            if(charArr[j] != null)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean isSubStringAnagram(String firstStr, String secondStr){
        int secondLength =  secondStr.length();
        int firstLength =  firstStr.length();
        if(secondLength == 0) return true;
        if(firstLength < secondLength || firstLength == 0) return false;
        //System.out.println("firstLength:"+ firstLength +" secondLength:" + secondLength+ 
                //" firstLength - secondLength:" + (firstLength - secondLength));

        for(int i = 0; i < firstLength - secondLength +1; i++){
            if(isAnagram(firstStr.substring(i, i+secondLength),secondStr )){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("isSubStringAnagram(xyteabc,ate): "+ isSubStringAnagram("xyteabc","ate"));

    }

}
```