# Find all letters of a string in another string

Tags: python

I'm working on a project that find all anagrams of a word with many others words.
For that I need a function that takes 2 strings and return True if all letters of str1 are in str2.

I made this code:

```
def almost_anagram(str1, str2):
    tmp = list(str2)
    for i in str1:
            if i in tmp:
                    tmp.remove(i)
            else:
                    return False
    return True
```

For exemple:

```
 almost_anagram("OLLE", "HELLO") = True
 almost_anagram("OOLE", "HELLO") = False
```

But is there a better/faster way to do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anagram of String 2 is Substring of String 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32069724/anagram-of-string-2-is-substring-of-string-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i prefer using count() function and by the way you don't need to convert the string into list:

```
def almost_anagram(str1, str2):
    for i in str1:
        if(str1.count(i)==str2.count(i)):
            pass
        else:
            return False
    return True

print(almost_anagram('olle','hello'))
print(almost_anagram('oole','hello'))
```

output:

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which essentially represents a multi-set:

```
import collections

def almost_anagram(word1, word2):
    counter1 = collections.Counter(word1)
    counter2 = collections.Counter(word2)
    return counter1 - counter2 == {}
    # alternatively:
    # return all(counter2[k] >= v for k, v in counter1.items())
    # return counter1 & counter2 == counter1
```

The code could be simplified to `return counter1 < counter2` if `Counter` supported subset-testing with `<` like sets do, but unfortunately it doesn't.

Output:

```
>>> almost_anagram("OLLE", "HELLO")
True
>>> almost_anagram("OOLE", "HELLO")
False
```

Comment: You can also subtract the resulting `Counter` objects. 
Something like `return counter1 - counter2`

Comment: @bro-grammer You mean like `return counter1 - counter2 == {}`? I guess that works. Thanks!

Comment: Yes or `bool(counter1 - counter2)`?

Comment: You'd have to negate that to get the correct result. It's probably more performant, but I prefer it to be more readable :)

Comment: Ah yes you are right! Didn't though of negation. It would definitely suffer the readability.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `list comprehension` with `all` should be faster.

**Ex:**

```
def almost_anagram(str1, str2):
    return all(str2.count(i) >=  str1.count(i) for i in set(str1))

print(almost_anagram("OLLE", "HELLO"))
print(almost_anagram("OOLE", "HELLO"))
```

**Output:**

```
True
False
```

Comment: You don't need to create a list, and `True if some_condition else False` is equivalent to simply `some_condition`... So basically `all(str2.count(i) >=  str1.count(i)  for i in str1)`

Comment: @Julien. Thanks

Comment: And this is potentially very inefficient since you are re-counting your letters every time, just count them once at the start, then loop.

Comment: I would recommend including `str.lower()` as well in case of "HELLO", or "hello".

Comment: @Julien He is just re-counting the non-unique ones, not all. Creating a set from `str1` and iterating through that would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

With `collections.Counter` object to get letter counts at once:

```
import collections    

def almost_anagram(str1, str2):
    str1_cnt, str2_cnt = collections.Counter(str1), collections.Counter(str2)
    return all(k in str2_cnt and str2_cnt[k] == v 
               for k,v in str1_cnt.items())
```

Test:

```
print(almost_anagram("OLLE", "HELLO"))  # True
print(almost_anagram("OOLE", "HELLO"))  # False
```

Comment: you can subtract objects of type `collections.Counter()`. I think that would make it faster